# Failed to validate domain yaml file

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am facing "Failed to Validate your Domain.yaml file:, invalid domain" while building chatbot using Rasa-NLU and Rasa-Core.

Have checked with online yaml code syntax also, and seems to be validate yml file. Still facing the issue

Unable to proceed further please help. the domain file seems fine when checked online

Domain yml:

```
slots:
  Hardware:
   type: text
  Software:
   type: text  
  Network:
   type: text


intents:
 -greet
 -goodbye
 -Accept
 -Reject
 -Software_Issue
 -Network_Issue
 -Hardware_Issue


entities:
 - Hardware
 - Software
 - Network

templates:
  utter_greet:
    - 'Hello! I am your IT Helpdesk bot to help you with Software, Hardware and Network Issues. May I know how can I help you?'
    - 'Hi! I am your IT Helpdesk bot to help you with Software, Hardware and Network Issues. May I know how can I help you'
  utter_goodbye:
    - 'Bye bye , Have a nice day Ahead'
  utter_Software_issue_and_seek_permission_for_raising_ticket:
    - 'I understand you have a software issue,Shall I raise ticket on behalf of you for the same?'
  utter_Hardware_issue_and_seek_permission_for_raising_ticket:
    - 'I understand you have a hardware issue,Shall I raise ticket on behalf of you for the same?'
  utter_Network_issue_and_seek_permission_for_raising_ticket:
    - 'I understand you have a network issue,Shall I raise ticket on behalf of you for the same?'         


actions:
  -utter_greet
  -utter_goodbye
  -utter_Software_issue_and_seek_permission_for_raising_ticket
  -utter_Hardware_issue_and_seek_permission_for_raising_ticket
  -utter_Network_issue_and_seek_permission_for_raising_ticket
  -action_ITchatbot
```

Train file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging

from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy
from rasa_core.policies.memoization import MemoizationPolicy
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_core.train import interactive
from rasa_core.utils import EndpointConfig

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def run_ITHelpdesk_online(interpreter,
                      domain_file="IT_Helpdesk_domain.yml",
                      training_data_file='data/Stories.md'):
action_endpoint = EndpointConfig(url="http://localhost:5055/webhook")                                                                                        
agent = Agent(domain_file,
              policies=[MemoizationPolicy(max_history=2), KerasPolicy(max_history=3, epochs=3, batch_size=50)],
              interpreter=interpreter,
              action_endpoint=action_endpoint)

data = agent.load_data(training_data_file)                                      
agent.train(data)
interactive.run_interactive_learning(agent, training_data_file)
return agent


if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")
  nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/nlu/default/ITchatbot')
  run_ITHelpdesk_online(nlu_interpreter)
```

Error:

```
INFO:rasa_nlu.components:Added 'nlp_spacy' to component cache. Key 'nlp_spacy-en'.
ERROR:pykwalify.core:validation.invalid
ERROR:pykwalify.core: --- All found errors ---
ERROR:pykwalify.core:["Value 'b'-greet -goodbye -Accept -Reject -Software_Issue -Network_Issue -Hardware_Issue'' is not a list. Value path: '/intents'"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- packages\rasa_core\domain.py", line 174, in validate_domain_yaml
 c.validate(raise_exception=True)
File "C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pykwalify\core.py", line 167, in validate
 error_msg=u'.\n - '.join(self.validation_errors)))
  pykwalify.errors.SchemaError: <SchemaError: error code 2: Schema validation failed:
- Value 'b'-greet -goodbye -Accept -Reject -Software_Issue -Network_Issue 
 -Hardware_Issue'' is not a list. Value path: '/intents'.: Path: '/'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "train_interactive.py", line 36, in <module>
run_ITHelpdesk_online(nlu_interpreter)
 File "train_interactive.py", line 25, in run_ITHelpdesk_online
action_endpoint=action_endpoint)
File "C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
 packages\rasa_core\agent.py", line 193, in __init__
self.domain = self._create_domain(domain)
 File 
     "C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
   packages\rasa_core\agent.py", line 648, in _create_domain
return Domain.load(domain)
 File 
     "C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
   packages\rasa_core\domain.py", line 88, in load
return cls.from_yaml(read_file(filename))
 File 
     "C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
   packages\rasa_core\domain.py", line 92, in from_yaml
cls.validate_domain_yaml(yaml)
 File 
    "C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
  packages\rasa_core\domain.py", line 176, in validate_domain_yaml
    raise InvalidDomain("Failed to validate your domain yaml. "
    rasa_core.domain.InvalidDomain: Failed to validate your domain yaml. Make 
  sure the file is correct, to do sotake a look at the errors logged during 
  validation previous to this exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

The domain file has to be formatted correctly.
You are missing spaces between the dash and your intents and actions also.

```
-greet       -> - greet
-utter_greet -> - utter_greet
```